# Lua string.match - matching on optional words in a string

Tags: regex, string, lua, match

I need a Lua pattern to match when 1 of 3 exact words are found at the start of a string but I can only find solutions online to show how to match against the type of characters, i.e. does it begin with a number or punctuation character.

For example, the following strings should match the pattern:

- `"player.position"`
- `"player.style"`
- `"target.width"`
- `"enemy.height"`

We can assume the first word will either be "player", "target" or "enemy" so can I create a pattern that groups them together and matches if only 1 of them is found in the string? The rest of the text after the "." can be anything.

I came up with this pattern but there are many problems with it:

```
local pattern = "[player target enemy]*%..+";
```

The first part can match any sequence of characters contained between the square brackets, so for example `"bannana_target_apple.position"` used with this pattern would return `"apple.position"` because `"a"`, `"p"`, `"l"`, and `"e"` are found between the square brackets in the pattern.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua pattern to match when 1 of 3 exact words are found at the start of a string:

```
if ({player=0, target=0, enemy=0})[your_string:match"^(%w+)%."] then 
   ... 
end
```

Comment: Shame there is no built in regex for specifying ordered sequence of characters but I really like your solution, very clever. Thanks.